# Forgot to check "install third party software" when installing Loki

Tags: release-loki, software-installation

So i had to reinstall loki because my harddrive dies, but i forgot to check the 3d-party apps box but i really want the 3d-party apps. Is there any way for me to enable 3d-party apps after the installation? Also, i don't want to reinstall elementary because i have a lot of data on it and don't want to wait 3 hours for the backup to be made, then reinstall and then reinstall my backup.

Thanks in regards, Davin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

The next time I suggest you use a meaningful title for the problem :)

Comment: it gives this error: http://pastebin.com/MHVDqWmG

Comment: also, the title was a placeholder but forgot to edit it afterwards :-)

Comment: @DavinMiler Check your ouput. In the terminal type "sudo apt-get -f install" first and then "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras"

Comment: Nevermind, i just had to install the software update