# Can´t install ANYTHING from AppCenter

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

i have just installed elementary OS Loki 0.4, and at first everything was working well, but now I cant install anything from the AppCenter. Im only able to  install things if I use Synaptic or the Terminal, but the AppCenter seems to be bugged.

Hope anyone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

this should fix AppCenter issues

Answer (score 0):

So, do you not see the other apps or do they not want to install. If the first i would like to redirect you here: [Forgot to check "install third party software" when installing Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9059/forgot-to-check-install-third-party-software-when-installing-loki) . Otherwise, try rebooting and only try to install one app at a time.